# GMP can't cope with a leading "+"?

Tags: c, gmp

Consider the following code

```
// BOGP.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gmp-static\gmp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>         /* For _MAX_PATH definition */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#define F(x) mpf_t x; mpf_init( x );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    F(foo);
    char * buff;
    mp_exp_t exp;

    mpf_init_set_str( foo, "123", 10 );
    buff = mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, foo);
    puts( buff );
    puts("\n");
    free(buff); 

    mpf_init_set_str( foo, "-123", 10 );
    buff = mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, foo);
    puts( buff );
    puts("\n");
    free(buff); 

    mpf_init_set_str( foo, "+123", 10 );
    buff = mpf_get_str(NULL, &exp, 10, 0, foo);
    puts( buff );
    puts("\n");
    free( buff );

}
```

In the first instance, after the mpf_get_str call, buff contains "123".
In the second, buff contains "-123".
But in the third, buff contains an empty string ("").

This is using GMP 4.2.4. Maybe I need to look in the manual again, but I would have thought that a leading "+" would have been handled as readily as a leading "-".

Comment: Also, if you're worried about this working cross platform, you'll want to change the \ in your #include to a / (since windows handles it either way, but unix systems don't) and not include malloc.h. malloc is declared in stdlib.h, not malloc.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, your issue is not mentioned anywhere in the [GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/#DOC).  You can, however, examine the code for [mpf_set_str](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#1WHZ8OTMs38/gmp-4.2.1/mpf/set_str.c&q=mpf_set_str) directly to see that it doesn't handle '+'.

I don't know what situation you need this in, but if you really need a character to indicate positive/negative, you might be able to take advantage of the fact that these functions ignore leading whitespace, thus using `" 123"`.

Comment: I looked at the source. It doesn't handle leading plus. (Sigh). Now to find a way of (re)building it on Windows.